# Breeze.js with asp.net web api odata and code first

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, code-first, breeze

I'm currently working on a proof of concept relating these technologies.

I've basically implemented what is suggested in this article, with the exception of using EF code first.

[Consuming an ASP.NET Web API OData Service with Breeze](http://briannoyes.net/2013/02/16/ConsumingAnASPNETWebAPIODataServiceWithBreeze.aspx)

An exception i.e.

**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'propertyRef' of undefined"**

gets thrown when executing this piece of client side code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my = {}; //my namespace
    $(function () {
        debugger;
        var serverAddress = "/odata/";
        breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });
        var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serverAddress);

        my.vm = {

            entities: ko.observableArray([]),
            load: function () {
                var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Customers");

                manager.executeQuery(query, function (data) {

                    var results = data.results;
                    $.each(data.results, function (i, c) {
                        my.vm.entities.push(c);
                    });

                })
                .fail(function (e) {

                    alert(e);
                }); ;
            }
        }

        my.vm.load();
        ko.applyBindings(my.vm);
    });

</script>
```

which originates in from this in the breeze.debug.js

```js
    function convertFromODataEntityType(odataEntityType, schema, metadataStore) {
    var shortName = odataEntityType.name;
    var ns = getNamespaceFor(shortName, schema);
    var entityType = new EntityType({
        shortName: shortName,
        namespace: ns
    });
    ---> **EXCEPTION HERE**--->var keyNamesOnServer = toArray(odataEntityType.key.propertyRef).map(__pluck("name"));
    toArray(odataEntityType.property).forEach(function (prop) {
        convertFromODataDataProperty(entityType, prop, schema, keyNamesOnServer);
    });

    toArray(odataEntityType.navigationProperty).forEach(function (prop) {
        convertFromODataNavProperty(entityType, prop, schema);
    });
    metadataStore.addEntityType(entityType);
    return entityType;
}
```

Querying the odata service via the url returns me the desired results, so its does not seem to be a data retrieval problem.

I've done some searching and the cause was suggested as breeze not handling inherited types as of yet.

In my case here I'm not using an inherited type.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an issue with a "key" not being defined for the EntityType in question.  Is there a key defined on the underlying server side entity type?

Answer (score 0):

You were right in saying the key is not defined. 
Looking at the ~/odata/$metadata in the browser the underlying CustomerId was not defined

```
<Key>
 <PropertyRef Name="CustomerId"/>
</Key>
```